# change background images in html

Tags: javascript, html

in folder i have following images  w1.jpg,w2.jpg......  w7.jpg, now i  have this code for display w1.jpg on my html page

```
<html>
<body >
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='w1.jpg' style='width:99%;height:99%' alt='[]' />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and i want to know,how to write script,which changes  images from w1.jpg to w7.jpg  in a specific  interval,as  i know for this there is used setInterval function in javascript,but could you help  to understand how i have to use it in my  code?thanks very much

Comment: Avoid fairly large chunks of inline css at all cost. Also, I don't understand why your image is 99 % width and height?

Comment: Note that the question is misleading - this is not a background image in the CSS sense, it is just a normal image element. It may appear as a background because of surrounding elements, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compulsory define image id

```
var i=2;
function change_image()
{
    if(i==8)
    {
        i=1;
    }

    var img="w"+i+'.jpg'
    document.getElementById("img1").src=img;
    i++;
    setTimeout("change_image()",5000);
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<img id="img1" src="w1.png" />
```

Call javascript function it will change image in 5 seconds

```
<script>
change_image();
</script>
```

Comment: no it just shows me all picture and then stops,i need continue it  whenever i open web page

Comment: now it works,just one question will it continue so if i add more and more images?

Comment: If your images name is as existing image name like w1.jpg w2.jpg .. then you can modify condition of javascript function like you have added 5 more images and its name as above mention name then you have put total +1 in conditon like(7+5=12) if(i==13){}

Answer (score 1):

I think you should background-image style for this. This is much better way than creating z-indexed div on the background.

Then change CSS by javascript (supposing you use jQuery for selecting body element):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ii = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
    var image = "w" + ii + ".jpg";
    console.log(image);
    $("body").css("background-image", "url('" + image + "')");
    ii++;
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Of course, you need to stop at the right time, when the last image comes.

Edit from comment below: If you don't want to use jQuery (however I encourage you to get familiar with it), you can change the line starting with `$` symbol to:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + image + "')";
```

Comment: you should add this is done in jquery. Not stand alone javascript. It uses a library called jquery

Comment: If you look at his css, he doesn't have background images - he has an image tag inside a div. It may look lika bg image because of the page layout, but it isn't

Comment: @fritzfromlondon Yes, that's right. However, is there any reason not to use background-image style for this? You can also create <ul> just with divs but it's not what you should do.

Comment: If you put a backgrouynd image behind an image element, the background won't be visibile (well, except for the bits where the imgage element is transparent, or if the surrounding div is larger then the img). Background image is fine, but then he would have to remove the image element from inside the div. There may be other reasons why ha wanted it in there.

Comment: Well, that's right. However, seeing the inline styles I suppose he just does not know about background-image. Am I wrong, @dato?

Comment: Hi, I've used an extra 3 bytes to convert your javascript to not rely on jQuery to save you 300 bytes of download time.
You wrote:

    $("body").css("background-image", "url('" + image + "')");

I say:

    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + image + "')";

Comment: @KernelJames Good point, I will mention it in the answer. Thanks

Comment: @PavelS.I suspect it's got to do with scaling the image to fill in the whole page... I'd rather stick to question as asked rather than make assumptions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well without getting into the details of how you could improve the code (avoid inline css, etc) the simplest way woud be to give the image an id, then put this this at the end of your HTML page

```
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img id="change-me" src='w1.jpg' style='width:99%;height:99%' alt='[]' />
 </div>
<script>
var
    images = [ "w1.jpg", "w2.jpg", "w3.jpg" ] //the list of images
  , imgToCHange = document.getElementById( 'change-me' )
  , interval = 1000 //in ms
  ;

setInterval( function(){
  images.unshift( images.pop() );
  imgToCHange.src = images[0];
 }, interval );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry slight mustake - try again. here's a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/4d2N7/